# Winforms Datagridview can't be refreshed from a delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, backgroundworker

I'm trying to load data from file to list and show that data immediately on Winforms' Datagridview. For that I've made the reading in another thread using Backgroundworker. The problem is, it only updates once and I can't get it to show more data. Not only that, when clicked, it tries to access element with -1 index, which of course doesn't exist, resulting in a crash.

Usually, from what I've  seen, simply adding again same data to data source `dataGridView1.DataSource = samelist;` should work, but not in this case.

BackgroundWorker's work

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    //lotsofCode...
    while (readData != null)
    {
        fooLists.Add(readData);
        //someCalculations...
        worker.ReportProgress();
    }
}
```

BackgroundWorker's progressChanged

```
private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { UpdateGridView(); });
}
```

UpdateGridView Method

```
private void UpdateGridView()
{
     if (fooLists.GetListById(1).calculatedList != null)
          dataGridView1.DataSource = fooLists.GetListById(1).calculatedList;
}
```

Later on I've read some threads on stack, where one suggested using `BindingSource` as a "middleman", so now I have `dataGridView1.DataSource = MyBindingSource;` in the component initialization and `tab1source.DataSource = fooLists.GetListById(1).calculatedList;` instead of `dataGridView1.DataSource`. It certainly helped, as the list is now clickable as it should be, but still there are only few records on a list.

None of `dataGridView1.Refresh()`, `dataGridView1.RefreshEdit()` or `dataGridView1.Update()` helped, though made the list loading slightly fancier (probably due to the delay they introduced :) ).

I tried making some "protections" (semaphores, so the delegate isn't called again, while working; try-catches, though no exceptions are thrown there; data clearing before re-writing...) but the "better version" worked as poor as this one and it only darkened the code.

Am I missing a way to update the Datagridview control? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type is fooLists?

Comment: @WithMetta It's a custom class with list of lists. The method returns standard List<T>.

Comment: Take a look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18a9762e-ac67-48a7-a372-55307fe344f3/how-do-you-refresh-data-bound-to-a-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols

You may need to call the parent control's refresh method. Also I'm not sure the expression "dataGridView1.DataSource = fooLists.GetListById(1).calculatedList;" effectively executes more than once. Think about it. You're setting the data source to the same object you already set it to. Maybe internally it checks for this and doesn't update the view if that's the case.

Comment: This may answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404453/datagridview-not-updating-in-ui-when-underlying-datasource-changes

Comment: @WithMetta Thanks, replacing List with BindingList helped. Not sure if I can accept answer in a comment though :P .

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't write it, but I think the reason that the items that you add to your dataSource are added to a collection that does not implement interface [IBindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx). You probably use a simple list to hold your read data.

If your 'DataSource`implements this interface, then after adding an item to your collection an event is raised. The class that holds the`DataSource`, whether it is a`DataGridView`or a`BindingSource` get notified about the changes in the list and update their contents accordingly.

Your solution would be to store your elements in an object of class [`System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx).

Suppose the items you want to show are of class `MyReadData`

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
         InitializeComponents();
         this.myReadItems = new BindingList<MyReadData>();
         this.MyBindingSource.DataSource = this.myReadItems;

         // if not already done in InitializeComponents
         this.MyDataGridView.DataSource = this.MyBindingSource;
    }

    private readonly BindingList<MyReadData> myReadItems;

    // whenever needed, start the BackGroundWorker.

    private void OnButtonReadFile_Click(object send, EventArgs e)
    {
         // create and start the backgroundworker
         BackGroundWorkdr worker = ...
         MyBackGroundWorkerParams params = ...
         worker.RunWorkerAsync(params);
    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // I am certain the sender is my BackGroundWorker:
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackGroundWorker)sender;
        MyBackGroundWorkerParams params = (MyBackGroundWorkerParams)e.Argument;

        // do some work using the params

        while (readData != null)
        {
            // some data read.
            // dont't add the data to the list, just report the data that must been added to the list:
            // someCalculations...
            int percentProgress = ...
            MyReadData dataToAddToGrid = ...
            worker.ReportProgress(percentProgress, dataToAddToGrid);
         }

         private void bw_progressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
         {
             // no need to call invoke, this is already the context of your forms thread
             Debug.Assert(!This.InvokeReguired);
             MyReadData dataToAdddToGrid = (MyReadData)e.UserState;
             this.myReadItems.Add(dataToAddToGrid);
         }
}
```

The main difference is that you should not let your `BackgroundWorker` to add data to the list of displayed data. The task of the BackGroundWorker is to read the data and to report to everyone who is interested what data has been read.

As it is the task of `MyForm` to display the read data, let `MyForm` decide which read data to display and in what format. This enhances reusage of both `MyForm` and `MyBackGroundWorker`: `MyForm` could display that that has been fetched in a different way, and `MyBackGroundWorker` could be used to inform others than `MyForm` to notify about read data.

Furthermore the display context of the progress changed event handler is the context of 'MyForm`, so an invoke is not needed.

You could also assign the IBindingList directly to the DataGridView, so without the use of a BindingSource. The only reason to keep a BindingSource is if you want access to the `Current` item, or if you want the freedom to fill your DataGridView with other items than the contents of your BindingList.

Finally: the most important part of the solution was that the items were added to an IBindingList.

`System.Components.BindingList<T>` is a class with limited functionality. If you want to order the rows in your `DataGridView`, or only show items that match some predicate, or combine items from several sources into one DataGridView, consider using [Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView/)

```
using Equin.ApplicationFramework;

public MyForm()
{
     InitializeComponents();
     this.myReadItems = new BindingListView<MyReadData>(this.components);
     this.MyBindingSource.DataSource = this.myReadItems;
     this.MyDataGridView.DataSource = this.MyBindingSource;
}

private readonly BindingListView<MyReadData> myReadItems;

 private void bw_progressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     MyReadData dataToAdddToGrid = (MyReadData)e.UserState;
     this.myReadItems.Add(dataToAddToGrid);
     // finished updating the list, DataGridView can be updated:
     this.myReadItems.Refresh();

     // this Refresh function allows you to change several items in the list
     // without unnecessary intermediate updates of your BindingSource and DataGridView
 }
```

Presto, that is all: free sorting or your columns by clicking on the column header. Consider examining their example project to see how filtering works and how to use several sources.

```
// Show only Brummies
this.myReadData.ApplyFilter(person => person.Address.City == "Birmingham");

// Remove the filter, show everyone again
this.myReadData.RemoveFilter();
```